# Animating multiple divs by switching their classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i am having a hard time trying to animate this box, so the changes go smooth, but i just cannot figure out how to keep everything together. Help would be really appreciated. (already tried with 'switchClass') Here is the whole code:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#box {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 167px;
    height: 167px;
}
#box .item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#box .over {
    height: 84%;
}
#box .other {
    height: 8%;
}
#top {
    background: red;
}
#mid {
    background: green;
}
#bot {
    background: blue;
}
</style>
<script>
function anim(item) {
    $('.item').attr('class', 'item other');
    $('#' + item.id).attr('class', 'item over');
}

function clean() {
    $('.item').attr('class', 'item');
}
</script>
<div id='box' onmouseout="clean()">
    <div id='top' class='item' onmouseover='anim(this)'></div>
    <div id='mid' class='item' onmouseover='anim(this)'></div>
    <div id='bot' class='item' onmouseover='anim(this)'></div>
</div>
```

edit: this code is running just fine, but its just an example of final output (just some animations needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not super cool, but seems to do job:

```
var $items = $('.item').on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $items.removeClass('over other');
        $items.stop().filter(this).animate({height: '84%'}, function () {
            $(this).addClass('over');
        })
        .end().not(this).animate({height: '8%'}, function () {
            $(this).addClass('other');
        });
    },
    reset: function() {
        $items.removeClass('over other').stop().animate({height: '33%'});
    }
});

$('#box').mouseout(function() {
    $items.trigger('reset');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/4vnkh/1/

Answer (score 1):

If your animation is based solely on CSS class attributes why not use CSS3 hover pseudo-selector?

Example:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
}

.box:hover {
    width: 400px;
}

<div class="box">Hover over me!</div>
```

---

### Additional: Response to comments

---

If you are looking for custom animation duration you can use a callback function with a duration for the initial function call.  Here's an example:

```
$('#div').animate({
   width: '200px',
   color: 'blue'
}, 5000, function() {
   // Animation finished after 5 seconds.
   alert("Animation complete!");
});
```

---

### Addition #2

---

Your problem child is this little guy:

```
$('.item').attr('class', 'item other');
```

This sets each box to 8% height and THEN expands the primary animating box.  Remove this and your #box will remain the same height throughout all animations!

Comment: I think i might not get my question straight. What I want is to get all this changes, that are already done, to have some duration.

Comment: I tried using simple animate and switchClass, but i couldnt manage to get the same result. The problem is that i need to have my 'box' stay same size as it is through the animation and using multiple animate functions or callbacks make it changes its height

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate the change, please take a look at [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Something like this:

```
$('.item').mouseenter(function() {
 $('.item').animate({
    height: 80%
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

$('.item').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.item').animate({
    height: 33%
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

in this case you don't need `onmouseout` or `onmouseover`